# How to plot a figure like this?

Tags: matlab, mesh

How to plot a figure like this

[image]

The data is like `f(x_i,t_j), i=1,2,..,M, j=1,2,...,N`. The horizontal axis is time `t` and vertical axis is space `x`

I know that `mesh` gives a 3-D plot and `surf` also gives 3-D surface, I wonder which command can give the above 2-D figure?

Comment: Did you look at the docs for them? Are you looking for just a 2D heatmap?

Comment: Read the docs for `imshow`, `colormap`.

Comment: Yeah, I've got what I need by you hint, 'imshow(f)` and then `colorbar'. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, I'd like to pick your answer as the right one if you put it to the answer region.

Comment: MATLAB's default color map, `parula`, is much, much better than the rainbow (`jet`) color map in the figure above. Please don't use `jet` to try to copy this figure. The rainbow color map was stabbed to death twenty years ago, but it keeps stumbling about and refusing to die.

Comment: Ok, that's very kind of you!

Comment: In addition to @CrisLuengo comment, if you want to know why `parula` is generally a better colormap than `jet` you can read [this excellent explaination](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html)

Comment: Wow, a great explaination!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a 2D heatmap, display your array as an image using [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), and add a [`colorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html).